# how to disable a button after click first time

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-navigation

how to disable a button after click first time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable a button, you have to set its `onPressed` method to null. You can use a ternary operator for this. So what I'm doing here is basically, giving a function to `onPressed` method conditionally. If _isButtonDisabled is false, onPressed method gets `null` which makes it disabled, otherwise it gets the function.

```
onPressed: _isButtonDisabled ? null : _functionThatDoesSomething,
```

You can put your _isButtonDisabled variable to your state, and set it to false in your `_functionThatDoesSomething` body. Probably at the end of the function.